# How can I put two NumPy arrays into a matrix with two columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to put two NumPy arrays into a matrix or horizontally stack them. Each array is 76 elements long, and I want the ending matrix to have 76 rows and 2 columns. I basically have a velocity/frequency model and want to have two columns with corresponding frequency/velocity values in each row.

Here is my code ('f' is frequency and 'v' the velocity values, previously already defined):

```
print(f.shape)
print(v.shape)
print(type(f))
print(type(v))
x = np.concatenate((f, v), axis = 1)
```

This returns

```
(76,)
(76,)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And an error about the *concatenate* line that says:

```
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I've also tried hstack except for *concatenate*, as well as vstack and transposing .T, and have the same error. I've also tried using Pandas, but I need to use NumPy, because when I save it into a txt/dat file, Pandas gives me an extra column with numbering that I do not need to have.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710672/create-2-dimensional-array-with-2-one-dimensional-array) should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your vectors are one-dimensional, like in this example:

```py
f_1d = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(f_1d.shape)

> (4,)
```

As you can see, only the first dimension is given. So instead you could create your vectors like this:

```py
f = np.expand_dims(np.array([1,2,3,4]), axis=1)
v = np.expand_dims(np.array([5,6,7,8]), axis=1)
print(f.shape)
print(v.shape)

>(4,1)
>(4,1)
```

As you may notice, the second dimension is equal to one, but now your vector is represented in matrix form.

It is now possible to transpose the matrix-vectors:

```py
f_t = f.T
v_t = v.T
print(f_t)

> (1,4)
```

Instead of using *concatenate*, you could use `vstack` or `hstack` to create cleaner code:

```py
x = np.hstack((f,v))
x_t = np.vstack((f_t,v_t))
print(x.shape)
print(x_t.shape)

>(4,2)
>(2,4)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much.

I have learned a bit of coding over 3 months just for my internship, and I still obviously lack a fundamental understanding of lists, vectors, matrices, arrays, dimensions etc. This helped me clear a lot of other things in my mind also. Thank you again.